# I want to my edittext first 6 characters should allow only alphabets and next characters should be only numbers

Tags: android-edittext

I want to my edittext  first 6 characters should allow only alphabets and next characters should be only numbers and whole edittext should not allow special characters

Comment: It's ok to want that, but what you've done so far interests us more.

Answer (score 0):

When you can get your hands on the text the user typed you can try putting it through a regular expression.  Java has a class, *java.util.regex.Pattern*, that can tell you whether a string fits a pattern.  (the *match* method)

Your pattern would be something like:

[\p{Alpha}][\p{Alpha}][\p{Alpha}][\p{Alpha}][\p{Alpha}][\p{Alpha}][\d]+

This regular expression says "six alphabet characters followed by one or more digits."

That's the best I can offer.  Your question is a bit vague.  Does the string the user enters have to have six letters?  Or is it one to six letters?  If it's the latter then my expression above is insufficient.  And what about the digits?  Is there a minimum number of digits required?